# Cookies in a httpRequest

Tags: http, browser, httpwebrequest

I want to know if all cookies travel in a request?

Here's a scenario:

1. Visit www.helloworld.com. A cookie named "cookie1" is created
2. Visit the www.alibaba.com.

Will "cookie1" go alongside the request when I visit www.alibaba.com?

Regards,
Salman.

Answer (score 1):

No, cookies are restricted by domain (and can also be restricted by path). Cookies from helloworld.com should not be visible to alibaba.com.

Read more on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Domain_and_Path

In particular: "The cookie domain and path define the scope of the cookie—they tell the browser that cookies should only be sent back to the server for the given domain and path. If not specified, they default to the domain and path of the object that was requested. [...] Cookies can only be set on the top domain and its sub domains. Setting cookies on www.foo.com from www.bar.com will not work for security reasons."